# Anorm get Int as result

Tags: scala, anorm

I have a code like this:

```
def getUserId(email: String) = DB.withConnection { implicit con =>
  SQL("select userId from signUp where email = {email}").
    on('email -> email).as(SqlParser.str("access_token").singleOpt)
}
```

It gives `String` as a result.

How can I get the result as `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Anorm documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Getting-a-more-complex-result), you can see how to use the row parsers.

For `Int`, either use `SqlParser.get[Int]`, or its convenient alias `SqlParser.int`.

There you are looking for a row with a single column, `.scalar` is better.

```
val res: Option[Int] = 
  SQL"SELECT userId FROM signUp WHERE email = $email".
    as(SqlParser.scalar[Int].singleOpt)
```

> Note the Anorm interpolation `SQL"..."` (without the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

i think its should work

```
def getUserId(email: String) = { 
    val userId = DB.withConnection { 
       implicit a => SQL( """ select userId from signUp where email = {email} """).on('email -> email).as(SqlParser.str("access_token").singleOpt) 
    } 
    userId.toInt 
}
```